# Accessing php session data in memcached aws elastic cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, php-8.2

I have two web servers (httpd,php8.2, and Memcached client installed on them).The two webservers behind an application load balancer.

I have created aws elastic Memcached for storing php session data. when my application tries to access php session data throwing an error.

`session_start(): Unable to clear session lock record in` 
`[22-May-2023 08:52:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to read session data: Memcached`

But when my application tries to access php session data single web server behind application load balancers work fine.

Comment: Did you try setting memcached sess_lock_retries, sess_lock_wait_min, and sess_lock_wait_max in the ini file?

Comment: @ArpitJain When changing memcached sess_lock_retriesnow it decreases the number of time in days. but sometimes still i am getting this error.